# Cisco AXL - Execute SQL Query, parse response

Tags: java, spring-boot, cisco-axl

`AXL 12.5`, `Apache CXF 3.3.6`, `OpenJDK 14`, `Spring Boot 2.3.0`, executing a SQL query

```
String sqlStmt = "SELECT name FROM typeuserlocale";

ExecuteSQLQueryReq executeSQLQueryReq = new ExecuteSQLQueryReq();
executeSQLQueryReq.setSql(sqlStmt);

ExecuteSQLQueryRes executeSQLQueryRes = axlPort.executeSQLQuery(executeSQLQueryReq);

List<Object> rows = executeSQLQueryRes.getReturn().getRow();
```

gives a response of `List<Object>`, how to parse the result? To what to cast the Object?

Debugging shows that it is a `ElementNSImpl`. Trying to cast it to `ElementNSImpl` led to the IDE adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But casting it led to an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to class org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl is in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap'; 
org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast has to be done to `org.w3c.dom.Element`, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the AXL service stubs were generated using the Oracle JDK version of wsimport, while your app is running with OpenJDK?  In which case, you can try regenerating using OpenJDK wsdl2java (not sure if there would be any resulting changes in the client code.)

There is a working Cisco DevNet sample here which demonstrates  parsing: https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/axl-java-samples , however it is based on Oracle JDK 1.8